# C++ Queue::Pop function acts weird when compiled with -O1

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, memory, queue

I have been writing my own queue in c++.
The problem is that it has a function called Queue::Pop() which calls the destructor of the first item in the queue which is kept track of by an index called _First, and afterwards _First is incremented and _Length is decremented.
When normally compiled, it performs as expected, however when -O1 flag is added, it starts acting weird and does not call the object's destructor properly.
The printing in destructor happens but the Id is not set to -1.
and as result, when the queue goes out of the scope, the memory is delete[] ed and destructors are called again and that is invalid code since if it was a file descriptor, it would be closed twice.
here is the Pop function:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <initializer_list>

namespace Core
{
    namespace Iterable
    {
        template <typename T>
        class Span
        {
        private:
            size_t _Length = 0;
            T *_Content = nullptr;

            inline T &_ElementAt(size_t Index)
            {
                return this->_Content[Index];
            }

            inline const T &_ElementAt(size_t Index) const
            {
                return this->_Content[Index];
            }

        public:
            Span() = default;
            Span(size_t Size) : _Length(Size), _Content(new T[Size]) {}

            Span(size_t Size, const T &Value) : _Length(Size), _Content(new T[Size])
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < _Length; i++)
                {
                    _Content[i] = Value;
                }
            }

            Span(Span &&Other) : _Length(Other._Length), _Content(Other._Content)
            {
                Other._Content = nullptr;
                Other._Length = 0;
            }

            Span(const Span &Other) : _Length(Other._Length), _Content(new T[Other._Length])
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < Other._Length; i++)
                {
                    _Content[i] = Other._Content[i];
                }
            }

            Span(const T *Array, size_t Size) : _Length(Size), _Content(new T[Size])
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < Size; i++)
                {
                    _Content[i] = Array[i];
                }
            }

            Span(std::initializer_list<T> list) : _Length(list.size()), _Content(new T[list.size()])
            {
                size_t i = 0;
                for (auto &item : list)
                {
                    _Content[i] = item;
                    i++;
                }
            }

            ~Span()
            {
                delete[] _Content;
                _Content = nullptr;
            }

            inline T *Content()
            {
                return _Content;
            }

            inline const T *Content() const
            {
                return _Content;
            }

            inline size_t Length() const
            {
                return _Length;
            }

            T &operator[](const size_t &Index)
            {
                if (Index >= _Length)
                    throw std::out_of_range("");

                return _ElementAt(Index);
            }

            const T &operator[](const size_t &Index) const
            {
                if (Index >= _Length)
                    throw std::out_of_range("");

                return _ElementAt(Index);
            }

            Span &operator=(const Span &Other)
            {
                if (this != &Other)
                {
                    _Length = Other._Length;

                    delete[] _Content;
                    _Content = new T[_Length];

                    for (size_t i = 0; i < _Length; i++)
                    {
                        _Content[i] = Other._Content[i];
                    }
                }

                return *this;
            }

            Span &operator=(Span &&Other)
            {
                if (this != &Other)
                {
                    delete[] _Content;

                    _Content = Other._Content;
                    _Length = Other._Length;

                    Other._Content = nullptr;
                    Other._Length = 0;
                }

                return *this;
            }
        };

        template <typename T>
        class BQueue final
        {
        public:
            // Constructors

            BQueue() = default;
            BQueue(size_t Size, bool Growable = true) : _Content(Size), _First(0), _Length(0), _Growable(Growable) {}
            BQueue(std::initializer_list<T> list) : _Content(list), _First(0), _Length(list.size()), _Growable(true) {}

            BQueue(const BQueue &Other) : _Content(Other._Content), _First(Other._First), _Length(Other._Length), _Growable(Other._Growable) {}
            BQueue(BQueue &&Other) : _Content(Other._Content), _First(Other._First), _Length(Other._Length), _Growable(Other._Growable)
            {
                Other._First = 0;
                Other._Length = 0;
                Other._Growable = true;
            }

            // Operators

            BQueue &operator=(const BQueue &Other)
            {
                if (this != &Other)
                {
                    _Content = Other._Content;
                    _First = Other._First;
                    _Length = Other._Length;
                    _Growable = Other._Growable;
                }

                return *this;
            }

            BQueue &operator=(BQueue &&Other)
            {
                if (this != &Other)
                {
                    _Content = std::move(Other._Content);
                    _First = std::move(Other._First);
                    _Length = std::move(Other._Length);
                    _Growable = std::move(Other._Growable);

                    Other._First = 0;
                    Other._Length = 0;
                    Other.Growable = true;
                }

                return *this;
            }

            T &operator[](size_t Index)
            {
                if (Index >= _Length)
                    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");

                return _Content.Content()[(_First + Index) % Capacity()];
            }

            T const &operator[](size_t Index) const
            {
                if (Index >= _Length)
                    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");

                return _Content.Content()[(_First + Index) % Capacity()];
            }

            // Peroperties

            size_t Capacity() const
            {
                return _Content.Length();
            }

            size_t Length() const
            {
                return _Length;
            }

            bool Growable() const
            {
                return _Growable;
            }

            T *Content()
            {
                return _Content.Content();
            }

            T const *Content() const
            {
                return _Content.Content();
            }

            inline bool IsWrapped() const
            {
                return _First + _Length > Capacity();
            }

            inline bool IsEmpty() noexcept { return _Length == 0; }

            inline bool IsFull() noexcept { return _Length == Capacity(); }

            inline size_t IsFree() noexcept { return Capacity() - _Length; }

            // Helper functions

            T &Head()
            {
                AssertNotEmpty();

                return _Content.Content()[_First];
            }

            T const &Head() const
            {
                AssertNotEmpty();
                
                return _Content.Content()[_First];
            }

            // Remove functionality

            void Pop()
            {
                std::destroy_at(std::addressof(Head()));

                --_Length;
                _First = (_First + 1) % Capacity();
            }

        private:
            Iterable::Span<T> _Content;
            size_t _First = 0;
            size_t _Length = 0;
            bool _Growable = true;

            inline void AssertNotEmpty()
            {
                if (IsEmpty())
                    throw std::out_of_range("Instance is empty");
            }
        };
    }
}

class Messenger
{
public:
    int Id = -1;

    Messenger() = default;
    Messenger(size_t id) : Id(id)
    {
        std::cout << Id << " Constructed" << std::endl;
    }

    Messenger(Messenger &&Other) : Id(Other.Id)
    {
        Other.Id = -1;
    }

    Messenger(Messenger const &Other) : Id(Other.Id) {}

    Messenger &operator=(Messenger &&Other)
    {
        Id = Other.Id;
        Other.Id = -1;
        return *this;
    }

    Messenger &operator=(Messenger const &Other)
    {
        Id = Other.Id;
        return *this;
    }

    ~Messenger()
    {
        if (Id != -1)
        {
            std::cout << Id << " Destructed" << std::endl;
            Id = -1;
        }
    }
};

using namespace Core;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Iterable::BQueue<Messenger> Queue{1, 2};

    Queue.Pop();
    Queue.Pop();

    std::cout << "Finished" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And here the output that i get:

```bash
1 Constructed
2 Constructed
1 Destructed
2 Destructed
Finished
2 Destructed
1 Destructed
```

As you can see, after printing Finished, nothing else must be printed.

Comment: And by the way this only happens in gcc not with clang!

Comment: I wanted to toss this at a few sanitizers, but the code wasn't complete enough to not get a mess of compiler errors: https://godbolt.org/z/5KMn3Pxze

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: What does `AssertEmpty` does? Shouldn't it be `AssertNotEmpty` instead? Compilers can optimize the code based on assertions. If an assertion is bogus, they can assume wrong things. By the way `std::move(Other.Id)` is useless since move does noting to primitives types like integers.

Comment: @JérômeRichard You are right I changed the naming but still the problem is elsewhere

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you and I have updated the code now you can just copy it into the compiler explorer and it works

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/8GKjod3vr

Comment: @user4581301 Dont forget to add -O1 flag too.

Comment: btw identifiers that start with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved. It is highly unlikely but this alone could explain anything because strictly speaking your code has undefined behavior due to using names like `_First` and `_Lenght`

Comment: yes it compiles and produces no output after the line that says "Finished"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Dont forget to add -O1 to reproduce the same result.

Comment: oh right https://godbolt.org/z/9q171z3dx. I would actually try to see what happens after you got rid of the reserved identifiers. `_First` and `_Lenght` arent too uncommon names. If thats not the cause then at least you can exclude something that is definitely UB

Comment: btw minimal reproducible example should also be minimal. I guess there are many methods you could remove because they arent called anyhow

Comment: `-O1`. That's good to know otherwise I'd use `-O3` to see how bad it got.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I did not know that thanks! However I have changed the names to something else (PresentCount) and still get the same result :/

Comment: The super-secret reason we like [mre]s (MREs) around here isn't because they make our job easy, it's because they usually make our job unnecessary. As the asker gets closer and closer to an optimal MRE, there's less and less code and fewer places for bugs to hide. Typically you'll get a few divide and conquer passes into making the MRE and the reduction in noise makes the bug and its solution obvious. Make the MRE early and you're usually done early.

Comment: @user4581301 you can also try -O3 but the result is the same.

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. I was trying to commend you for providing such a vital piece of information in the question. You'd be surprised how many don't and still expect a good answer.

Comment: @user4581301 no need to apologize i undrestood you and thabk you for takin the time and giving me info on how to present the question better. What I ment was that this problem only occurs with gcc with any levwl of optimization and surprisingly not with clang!

Comment: Even more interesting if you change the member variable to `volatile int Id = -1;`, and in the destructor add `Id = -86;`.

Comment: I think the problem is that `std::destroy_at` will destruct the object in the array, but `delete[] _Content;` will *also* destruct the already destructed objects in the array.

Comment: Has anyone reported this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok with the help of Jason turner and Bjarne Stroustrup on linkedin I was able to find the problem.

The problem is using Span to hold the data!
When Span goes out of scope it will call all of the destructors of the array objects despite the fact not all of them are constructed and need to destructed which will cause double free-ing.
To solve this I wrote a Memory holder class which only does malloc(new) and free(delete) and in the BQueue's destructor it disposes only the objects from _First to _First + _Length and not others which are not constructed.

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup, the creator of C++, fixed your code via LinkedIn?

Comment: @JohnZwinck He helped me through it

Comment: That's amazing.  You can accept your own answer (might have to wait a bit longer before the site lets you do that, but you should do it when you can).  Congratulations on getting the father of C++ to answer your query!